# XLA_GPU is showing instead of GPU in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 2.3. version. When checking about device available, it is showing xla-gpu. I've code which can run on gpu only(not on xla-gpu). Anyone can enlighten me why it is showing like this and the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

When building tensorflow from source in the bazel there is option where you can set XLA-enable or disable. If you have build it from source then make sure you have chosen "No" in XLA option.

If installed using pip, then you can try other version of tensorflow like 2.4. It should work